# I deleted my Trash file/folder

Tags: nautilus, delete, trash

I need help... I had an extension that wouldn't uninstall - so I moved its file to trash. However, once the file was sent to trash; the trash couldn't be emptied... I read that If I deleted my trash file it would empty it out and repair itself upon needing to be used by another program or if I sent anything to it.

This is where it's weird. I can still sent to trash, but whatever gets sent to the trash is gone into oblivion. Trash says its empty, and whatever I send to trash cannot not be found. Moreover, I still have a trash icon on my desktop. It just doesn't hold anything.

Also, I know it was a ridiculous decision to delete an operational file and function from my system. I don't need to be told how dumb it was. So please no trolls. I am pretty new to Linux.

Overall, I just need help repairing my trash file/folder. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver. Loving it. But this one thing is driving me crazy. I have searched for the answer everywhere - But it seems no one has been this stupid before.

---

Here's what the output from `ls -ld ~/.local/share/Trash`:

```
$ ls -ld ~/.local/share/Trash
drwx------ 4 syrefire root 4096 Dec 13 13:57 /home/syrefire/.local/share/Trash
```

Comment: The Trash folder (for your user: `~/.local/share/Trash`) should indeed be automatically generated if necessary. I could only imagine that this doesn't work if your parent folder has messed up permissions or ownership. Can you [edit] your question and add the output of typing `ls -ld ~/.local/share/{Trash,}` to show that information?

Comment: After Navigating to my .local/share/Trash/files... I have found the files that were sent to trash. I hope that tidbit helps. However a right click on trash says that trash is completely empty "no files".

Comment: So, I deleted a file at root level out of trash folder... Wham Bam, thank you Ma'am - it's fixed. I was/am able to see icon in "Full" mode. Right clicked and "empty Trash" was not greyed out. I selected and trash responded.

The file I removed was a Gnome extension file - if that matters.

Anyway, thank you Byte Commander, for taking any time at all to help out a newbie. Cheers!

Comment: Nice that you could fix it. You can post what you did in the answer section below and mark that answer as accepted to show your problem is solved and to help other people find your solution if they run into the same issue. Also, looking at your output, the folder belonged to the `root` group instead of your own. While this alone should not have made a difference, it might be an indicator that you could have had more problems with incorrect ownership or permission configuration there.